# Java-Springboot SOAP dynamic client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap-client

I am building an app to support SOAP call dynamically. Please suggest me if there is a library in Java Spring-boot I can use and point me to samples if there are any.

I was trying to use Apache CXF but it is not working as expected. Example lot if issues with type conversation when sending the input data below is the sample code I am trying.

```
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client client = dcf.createClient("http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl");
Object[] res = client.invoke("Add", 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html) the documentation from Spring about the WebServiceTemplate.

This guide [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) is also showing you how to generate classes with JAXB and use them with the WebServiceTemplate.